# How to use dynamic key name in object during object construction?

Tags: javascript, object-properties, object-construction, dynamic-properties, object-notation

I want to use a dynamic key name **during the creation** of the object.

```
var myKey = 'text';
var myObj = {
    [myKey]: 'Hello'  // not working
};
alert(myObj.text);
```

I know you can do it on the next line after the object is created `myObj[key] = 'someValue'`, but I was curious about doing it when you're creating the object.

There's a plethora of similar questions about it, but they all do it after the object has been created using the `[]` notation.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really worth it to save one line? I guess if you really want to be hacky, you could do this:

```
var myKey = 'text';
var myObj = JSON.parse( '{"' + myKey + '": "Hello"}' );
alert(myObj.text);
```

I would actually just declare the object and set the key

```
var myKey = 'text';
var myObj = {};
myObj[myKey] = "Hello";
alert(myObj.text);
```

Comment: You're right if it's just saving one line, but when there are many occurrences, it doubles your lines (per the example). And this is fine if there's no good alternative, but I wanted to see what the SO js community experts had to say about it.